# Overlapping two plots with different dates

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm have a pandas dataframe with subscriber information and I'm attempting to plot two graphs on the same figure to see the change over the same period of time at two different instances. The dataframe resembles:

```
df = 
      Date                   1_Month_Sub       3_Month_Sub 
0     2010-01-01 00:00:00    2                 4
1     2010-01-02 00:00:00    1                 1
2     2010-01-03 00:00:00    3                 6
3     2010-01-04 00:00:00    0                 3 
4     2010-01-05 00:00:00    2                 1   
...
1381  2014-01-01 00:00:00    4                 3
1382  2014-01-02 00:00:00    2                 2 
1383  2014-01-03 00:00:00    3                 0
1384  2014-01-04 00:00:00    2                 4   
...
```

if I do the following

```
df.plot(x='Date', y=['Year Sold'], stacked=False, grid=True,
        xlim=['2011-10-01', '2011-10-31'], ylim=[0, 7], figsize=(40, 16), 
        marker='o', color='red')
df.plot(x='Date', y=['Year Sold'], stacked=False, grid=True,
        xlim=['2012-10-01', '2012-10-31'], ylim=[0, 7], figsize=(40, 16), 
        marker='o', color='green')
plt.show()
```

I get two separate figures. I would like to put both figures on the same graph.

I realize that the `x-axis` is different in both cases, one being January 2011, and the other being January 2012 and I'm not too sure how to change that to accommodate both graphs. The idea I had was to use the index but that's not very helpful when I select two different periods that aren't the same month but different years (for instance plotting a 15 day period in January 2011 and a 15 day period in May 2011). Is there a way to maybe have both axis present?

Comment: If you want both figures on the same graph, make the x axes the same. If both datasets are 15 day periods you could use the ordinal day of the period as the x axis.

Comment: As @SohierDane said, you have to shift your data to fit in the same x axis. Either that, or use matplotlib directly, in particular [`pyplot.twiny`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.twiny).